# Is it possible to mark an SQLite DB as a non-corrupt one

Tags: sqlite, recovery, repair

I have aborted vacuum with ctrl+c and deleted the journal (I thought it is useless for that case). Now it writes that the db is corrupt. I wonder if it is possible to mark the DB as non-corrupt without recreating it by translation to sql and back.

Comment: in which system? since sqlite DB is simple file, I don't think you can repair it if the file is corrupt. I might try to open it with sqlite3 command line tool and try to see if I can fetch some data

Comment: here is a tool for repairing corrupt sqlite db (didn't try it myself):
http://www.pldaniels.com/undark/

Comment: 1 I don't think it is actually corrupt. Vacuum just rebuilds the db into another file and replaces the old file with the new one. But it seems that the old file has somewhere a marker which says "the journal was used, use it for rollback, if missed - recognize the file  as broken". But there shouldn't be anything to rollback in the case of vacuum. 2 It's not in place, it exports into csv. All I need is to mark the file as clean. But sqlite header has no such a field, it seems it is somewhere deeper.

Comment: sqlite has built-in repair tool. once you open the DB with sqlite it is repaired

Comment: @KOLANICH There is no separate marker; you get that error message when SQLite detects inconsistent data in the DB.